# How to enforce and apply at most (or exactly) one entity with true flag within a partition in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a small collection of documents at a partition. I'd like to mark exactly one of these entities as enabled within the partition. Being enabled is indicated by the document having an `isEnabled` flag set to true. When a document is updated or inserted with `isEnabled` set to true, within that transaction all other documents should be `isEnabled:false`. If a document is being deleted or transitioning from `isEnabled` true to false, then the last modified document should become the enabled if there are any record remaining. The partition should never get into an inconsistent state. It should only be possible to have exactly one enabled document unless there are zero documents

Is there a pattern for implementing this kind of state? I've attempted a few approaches but they all seem to have some holes in them.

Comment: `I've attempted a few approaches but they all seem to have some holes in them` - Please edit your question and include the approaches you have attempted and the issues you ran into with them.

Comment: Did the provided answers help solve your issue? If so, please consider accepting one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [unique keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys). And call it `disabledAt` instead of `isEnabled`.

When you need to switch the active document, you can open a [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency).

1. Begin transaction
2. On the old document, set `disabledAt` to the current UTC datetime or ticks
3. On the new document, set `disabledAt` to null or remove it
4. Commit transaction

You can do transactions via the SDK or via User-Defined-Functions. You can probably also use [post-triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript#triggers), since they run within the same transaction.

This will guarantee that you only have one document without a value for `disabledAt`. It works because you can do transactions with guaranteed consistency as long as you stay within a single partition.

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be to move this state into a dedicated item, rather than distributing it among the items. This single metadata item per partition would have a property like `activeItemId` and be set to either the `id` of active document or null if none active.

The active item would be subject to last-write-wins semantics, and you could use the change feed or a maintenance job to check for orphaning if you can't enforce at the application layer. Even if the `activeItemId` ended up pointing at a removed item, a read attempt with 404 could be used as a double-check at read time.